# Why is this piecewise function failing an object type assertion test?

Tags: python, piecewise

I need to create a piece-wise function in Python, which I have done, and I need to run through a couple of tests. I ended up creating a code that creates the plot and a second code for the conditions I have to meet... I didn't know how to incorporate the conditions in the vectorized version of the code,  and I couldn't figure out to plot my longer code with all of the conditions in it.

If you could help with that, that'd be awesome, but my main concern is the assertion test. Here are the two codes:
The code with conditions is failing the assert type(out[4]) in [float, np.float64] part, but I don't know why as it seems to be doing assert type(out[1]) in [float, np.float64] just fine. 
Thank You

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from nose.tools import assert_equal, assert_raises
import warnings
# this is the code for the plot (vectorised form?)
def pwfun(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    y += ((x >= -1) & (x <= 1)) * 0
    y += (x > 1) * (x*x - 1)
    y += (x < -1) * (-2*x - 2)
    return y
    raise NotImplementedError

# print(pwfun(x = [-6.0, -0.5 , 0.2,  7]))
# print(pwfun([-2, 0.5, 3]))
x = np.linspace(-4,3)
plt.plot(x,pwfun(x), 'r')
plt.show()
# I couldn't figure out a way to make the bottom one show a plot.

   # this is the code for meeting the conditions

def pwfun(x):
    blah=[]
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for i in x:
            if i < -1:
                if isinstance(i, float):
                    blah.append(round(-2 * i - 2))
                else:
                    blah.append( int(-2 * i - 2))
            elif ((i <= 1) and (i >= -1)):
                blah.append( 0)
            else:
                if isinstance(i, float):
                    blah.append(round(i * i - 1 , 2))
                else:
                    blah.append(int(i * i - 1))
        return blah
    else:
        if (x < -1):
            if isinstance(x, float):
                return round(-2 * x - 2, 2)
            else:
                return int(-2 * x - 2)
        elif ((x <= 1) and (x >= -1)):
            return 0
        else:
            if isinstance(x, float):
                return round(x * x -1, 2)
            else:
                return int(x * x -1)
```

```
assert pwfun(-3) == 4
assert pwfun(0.56) == 0
assert pwfun(4) == 15

x = [-6.0, -0.5 , 0.2,  7]
assert pwfun(x) == [10, 0, 0, 48]
x = [-7/2, -2.5, -1, 0 , 1, 2, 3.2]
assert pwfun(x) == [5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9.24]
## testing whether the entries are of appropriate type


x = [-3.0, 2.3, -7/2, -2.5, -1.4]
out = pwfun(x)      

assert type(out[0]) == int  # int
assert type(out[1]) in [float, np.float64]  ## float | np.float64
assert type(out[2]) == int
assert type(out[3]) == int
assert type(out[4]) in [float, np.float64] # THIS IS THE PART THAT FAILS
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. If you are going to post a question like this, you need to demonstrate at least some bare-minimum attempt at debugging this yourself, which would likely reveal to you the exact nature of the problem (e.g. try *printing the problematic ouput*)

Comment: The proper way to check types in Python would involve using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance): i.e. `assert isinstance(out[4], (float, np.float64))`

Comment: `round(-2 * x - 2, 2)` works just fine if `x` is an `int`; there's no need to write two branches of code. There's also no need to basically double the size of your function just to save the caller from writing `pwfun([3])[0]` instead of `pwfun(3)`.